How make androidTest PeriodicWorkRequest for testDriver?
In my application, I use WorkManager with Hilt for periodic requests that run once a day. this is necessary to clear data across in the Room DAO.
I need to do a mock for my PeriodicWorkRequest. For this, I use WorkManagerTestInitHelper for the test drive inside the androidTest directory.
Scheduler worker:
private fun schedulerWorker() {
    val dailyWorkRequest =
        PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(ClearCacheWorker::class.java, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setInitialDelay(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
        "CleanCacheWork",
        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
        dailyWorkRequest
    )
}

My work with Inject:
@HiltWorker
class ClearCacheWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted appContext: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    private val movieDao: MovieDao,
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        Log.d("WORK_MANAGER", "doWork is run")

        return try {
            movieDao.clearTable()
            Log.d("WORK_MANAGER", "doWork is success")
            Result.success()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("WORK_MANAGER", "${e.message}")
            Result.retry()
        } finally {
            Log.d("WORK_MANAGER", "doWork completed")
        }
    }
}

My test (in androidTest):
@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class WorkerTest {

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    private lateinit var context: Context

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        hiltRule.inject()
        context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()

        val config = Configuration.Builder()
            .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.DEBUG)
            .setExecutor(SynchronousExecutor())
            .build()

        WorkManagerTestInitHelper.initializeTestWorkManager(context, config)
    }

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun testPeriodicWork() {
        val request = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(ClearCacheWorker::class.java, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .build()
        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)

        val testDriver = WorkManagerTestInitHelper.getTestDriver()
        workManager.enqueue(request).result.get()
        testDriver?.setPeriodDelayMet(request.id)

        val workInfo = workManager.getWorkInfoById(request.id).get()

        assertThat(workInfo.state, `is`(WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED))
    }
}

When I ran the WorkerTest, I got the next error:
java.lang.AssertionError:
Expected: is <SUCCEEDED>
but: was <FAILED>
at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:8)
at com.example.jetmoviepoalim.worker.WorkerTest.testPeriodicWork(WorkerTest.kt:59)



Could not instantiate com.example.jetmoviepoalim.worker.ClearCacheWorker
                                                                                                
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.jetmoviepoalim.worker.ClearCacheWorker. 
<init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]

Help me understand and fix the error.
